# mysql selective product insert if not exist

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I would like to insert rows from one table `products` (table1) and column named `text` into a second table where the table doesn't have the same row values of the `text2` columns using (like) i am referring to the `wp_posts` (table2) table.

First table: table1

```
id   |  text   
-------------
1       t1      
2       t2           
3       t3
4       t4
5       t5
6       t6
7       t7
8       t8
....
```

Second table: table2

```
id  |   text2
--------------
1   t1
2   t4
3   t6 t62
4   t8
5   t9
...
```

Expected result after select:

```
id  |   text2
--------------
1   t2
2   t3
3   t5
4   t7
...
```

this result i want to insert in table2

Expected result after insert in tabel2:

```
id   |  text   
-------------
1       t1      
2       t2           
3       t3
4       t4
5       t5
6       t6 t62
7       t7
8       t8
9       t9
....
```

and this result i want to inser in tabel 2 where these values are missing.

I tried something like this, but because the data tables have a large amount of that in them, more then 180000 entries, this takes a long time:

```
INSERT INTO table2 (text2)
SELECT t1.text, 
FROM table1 t1
JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.text LIKE CONCAT('%', t2.text2 ,'%')
```

Or how do i do something like this?:

```
SELECT text
FROM tabel1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT text2
                      FROM tabel2
                      WHERE text2 LIKE tabel1.text ????)
```

Or other idea to solve this problem?

Comment: I don't follow the logic at all for getting the results from the input data.

Comment: i have 2 table and i want to add the missing rows from table 1 to table 2 using text column and this columns is join using LIKE

Comment: Your first row is `1 t2`, this is in neither table.  I don't follow the logic ("Expected result after select").  Your results after the insert are just the contents of table1.

Comment: (Expected result after select) -> this result i want to add to table2 using insert before this select

Answer (score 0):

Assuming both your tables have unique keys on ID field...

```
insert into table2 (id, text2)
select id, text from table1
on duplicate key update
text2=concat_ws(' ',text2, values(text2));
```

UPDATE:

more elaborated variant to remove duplicates (Assuming the text from table1 describes unique items):

```
insert into table2 (id, text2)
select id, text from table1
on duplicate key update
text2=if(find_in_set(values(text2),replace(text2,' ',','))>0,
text2,concat_ws(' ',text2, values(text2)));
```

See difference between the two statements on SQL Fiddle: [first one](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cb545/1) vs [second one](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/be366/1).

Comment: but the ID key from the table1 in the some whit the ID from table2

Comment: That is why you have "on duplicate key update" clause. If ID in both your tables is a primary key, or at least a unique key, this query will result in inserting the rows where ID did not exist, and updating the rows where ID already existed.

Answer (score 0):

I would use your first query, but your logic is back to front: you are selecting the rows that *are* present, not the ones that *aren't*.

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO table2 (text2)
SELECT t1.text, 
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.text LIKE CONCAT('%', t2.text2 ,'%')
WHERE table2.text2 IS NULL
```

This left join will select all rows that *don't* match, because columns of missed joins are all null.

Regarding performance, this query is about as good as it gets, but your can make it run faster by starting a transaction, locking the target table, running the query then committing.

If that isn't fast enough, try exporting the query results then importing them into the target table in a separate step.